# Java expects an "AnnotationName" after a method declaration

Tags: java, methods, enums, annotations

I am coding a game in Java, and must create a method inside an enum type that returns whether the player may fill a bottle with liquid or not. The method checks whether the player's inventory contains a bottle, and whether the player is near a liquid.

In the method declaration, I am getting an error that says I need to put an "AnnotationName" after it. I do not know what an "AnnotationName" is, and on all the other methods I have created in the file there are no such errors.

There is also another error at the bottom of the enum on the closing bracket. It says "Please insert '}' to complete ClassBody". I have checked all the curly brackets in the file and they all have matches. I think this error must be tied to the above "AnnotationName" error. I have included the method below, as well as the enum type the method is a part of.

The method by itself:

```
//the problematic method
@Override
public boolean isAvailable() {
        
    //create var
    boolean bottleInInventory = false;
    //loop thru junk sublist
    for (int i = 0; i < Data.player.sizeOfSubList(0); i++) {

        //if current item is a Bottle, bottleInInventory = true; otherwise do nothing
        if (Data.player.getItem(ItemType.JUNK, i).getClass() == Bottle.class) {

            //set var to true
            bottleInInventory = true;

        }

        //repeat loop until a Bottle is found (or not found)
    }

    //check if player is near a liquid AND if they have a Bottle in their inventory
    //if they satisfy both conditions, return true
    try {

        if (Data.nearLiquid.get(0) != null && bottleInInventory) { //if index 0 has nothing in it, there must'nt be anything in the other indexes either.
    
            return true;
    
        }

    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) { //if the player is not near any liquids this will happen during the above if statement.

       return false;

    }

    return false; //if player is near a liquid and not in possesion of a Bottle

}
```

The whole enum:

```
    FILL_BOTTLE("Fill Bottle") {

        //this method is not complete
        @Override
        public void opCode() {
            
            boolean multipleBottles; //if there is more than one bottle or not
            ArrayList<Bottle> bottlesInInventory = new ArrayList<Bottle>(); //output of loop
            Item currentItem; //used only inside loop
            for (int i = 0; i < Data.player.sizeOfSubList(0); i++) { //loop counts how many bottles you have

                currentItem = Data.player.getItem(ItemType.JUNK, i);

                if (currentItem.getClass() == Bottle.class) {

                    bottlesInInventory.add((Bottle) currentItem); /* currentItem will always be assigned to a Bottle here,
                                                                   * but we still need to cast because the
                }                                                  * variable type is an Item. */

            }

            //multipleBottles is set to true if the bottlesInInventory list has more than one item in it
            if (bottlesInInventory.size() > 1) {
                multipleBottles = true;
            }

            System.out.println("You are currently able to fill your bottle with " + Data.nearLiquid.size() + " liquids near you");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Here they are:");

            for (int i = 0; i < Data.nearLiquid.size(); i++) {

                System.out.println((i + 1) + ") " + Data.nearLiquid.get(i).getName());                    

            }

            int liquid = Data.intPrompt("Which liquid would you like to fill your bottle with? ");

        }

        //the problematic method
        @Override
        public boolean isAvailable() {
            
            //create var
            boolean bottleInInventory = false;
            //loop thru junk sublist
            for (int i = 0; i < Data.player.sizeOfSubList(0); i++) {

                //if current item is a Bottle, bottleInInventory = true; otherwise do nothing
                if (Data.player.getItem(ItemType.JUNK, i).getClass() == Bottle.class) {

                    //set var to true
                    bottleInInventory = true;

                }

                //repeat loop until a Bottle is found (or not found)
            }

            //check if player is near a liquid AND if they have a Bottle in their inventory
            //if they satisfy both conditions, return true
            try {

                if (Data.nearLiquid.get(0) != null && bottleInInventory) { //if index 0 has nothing in it, there must'nt be anything in the other indexes either.
    
                    return true;
    
                }

            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) { //if the player is not near any liquids this will happen during the above if statement.

                return false;

            }

            return false; //if player is near a liquid and not in possesion of a Bottle

        }
    },
```

I've tried adding curly brackets, annotations (@Override), and researched on AnnotationNames but not had any luck. I can't find any documentation on what an AnnotationName is, and the curly brackets and extra annotations just created more errors.

Edit:

Here is a link to the entire file as well as a link to the github repo with my code.

[Option.java](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b4AVd3YbW3L7IHevxw34HxpIzVykz60G/view?usp=sharing)
[Jump The Volcano](https://github.com/foxler2010/jump-the-volcano)

Comment: That's not the whole enum, just one case of it and its closing bracket. The problem may be in the prior method.

Comment: Don't post links to code here. Post the code. Questions here must be self-contained. Nobody is going to follow your link.